# manually set validity in bootstrap validator

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-ui

Is is possible to manually set field validity to invalid in [bootstrap validator](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/)?

I'm using angular js in my project and want to use date range validation.

The "max-date" attribute works fine except if I'm typing a date manually, that's why I want revalidate field in the controller and manually set field validity.

html:

```
    <div class="form-group inputGroupContainer" ng-controller="DatepickerCtrl">
        <label for="date">Date of Birth</label>
        <p class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="date1"  placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" class="form-control"  ui-date="{dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}" ui-date-format="dd/MM/yyyy" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="user.Personal.BirthDate" max-date="currentDate" is-open="opened" close-text="Close" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button"   class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
```

angularjs controller:

```
$scope.$watch('user.Personal.BirthDate', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                        if ($scope.user.Personal.BirthDate)
                            if ($scope.user.Personal.BirthDate.getTime() > new Date().getTime()) {
//set validity for "date1" to invalid
                            }
                        $($('#editPersonalForm')).bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'date1');
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This plugin has recently changed names ***formValidation*** and licensing but back at 0.5.0 this worked for me.

Force the status of an input to INVALID

```
/**
     * Update all validating results of field
     *
     * @param {String|jQuery} field The field name or field element
     * @param {String} status The status. Can be 'NOT_VALIDATED', 'VALIDATING', 'INVALID' or 'VALID'
     * @param {String} [validatorName] The validator name. If null, the method updates validity result for all validators
     * @returns {BootstrapValidator}
     */
$('#editPersonalForm').data('bootstrapValidator').updateStatus('date1', 'INVALID', null)
```

Comment: Very helpful tip in cases.